# Removing legends from a built-in plotting function in library

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I am using a library in R called [DVHmetrics](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DVHmetrics/DVHmetrics.pdf). The idea behind it is that you can take some data from a specific file, exported by another program, and pretty much read it and manipulate the data within. This also mean means it is not raw data I am working with here.

In this library there is a function called showDVH, which takes some of the data in the file you read and plot it. By looking at the code behind the library this plotting is done through ggplot. However, when using the function that does this plotting there is no option for showing/not showing legends. And the thing is I really need to remove the legends.

So is there a way where this is possible when it is not directly implemented in the function itself ?

Comment: Maybe try: `showDVH(mydata) + guides(colour = FALSE)` ?

Comment: to add to the comment of @ zx8754: `showDVH(...) + theme(legend.position="none")`. This removes all legends

Comment: When using showDVH(...) + theme(legend.position="none") the console output is just:

`> showDVH(...) + theme(legend.position="none")
NULL`

So I still get all the legends even though.

Comment: I've just checked the code of the function. The print is done inside the function. I guess you could try to save the ggplot in a variable `p <- showDVH(data)` and then change the plot `p <- p + theme(legend.position="none")` or `p <- p + guides(colour = FALSE)`. Then use `print(p)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package function returns list of ggplot objects, so we need to say "no legend" for each ggplot object in a list separately, see below example:

```
library(DVHmetrics)
library(ggplot2)

# for one patient
x <- showDVH(dataMZ, patID = "P123", show = FALSE)
x <- x$P123 + theme(legend.position = "none")
# plot
x

# for all patients
x <- showDVH(dataMZ, show = FALSE)
x <- lapply(x, function(i) i + theme(legend.position = "none"))
# plot
x
```